# Why would number lock be disabled by default?

Tags: keyboard, windows-os

There was a time that number lock was enabled by default (at least in a Windows environment).  Then, after an update one day, all the sudden the Number Lock is disabled.  Why the change?  What is it about disabling number lock that would be considered a better user experience?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this behaviour applies to all machines ... I've just checked a bunch of machines (3 laptops running Windows 7, one desktop running Windows XP, a netbook running Windows 8 and two virtual servers running Windows 2008 R2) and they all have numlock on by default.

Answer (score 7):

Some laptops don't have a dedicated numeric keypad.  Some of these laptops activate the function-key numbers when num-lock is activated.  And thus lots of users writes "He336 W6r3d" instead of "Hello world"  And if this is entered during logon, they only see "***********" ;-)

[image]

Comment: And laptops often have tiny warning lights to indicate number lock is turned on.