# Keyboard shortcut design methodology (for keyboard and touch screen)

Tags: desktop-application, keyboard-shortcuts

What sort of methodologies should I employ to choose which letters and shifting keys to assign to different functions?

Is underlining the accelerator letter the best practice, or should I spell out the combination?

If anyone has experience with choosing keyboard accelerators, or if there are any online reference out there or books on this topic would be a great help.

Please note there is no mouse in the product, so keyboard and touch is the only two means of navigation.

---

The case is that I am working on a "stand alone" touch screen product with a physical qwerty keyboard attached.  The keyboard is for users who sits in a controlled environment and has in depth knowledge of the product so they are looking to perform the task quickly and repetitively.  The touch screen is for users who operates in a dynamic environment and constantly multitasking between 4 to 6 different equipments.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that there is no mouse in the product, so keyboard and touch is the only two means of navigation.

Comment: I have added your comment to your question. It is pretty important information. And on the stackexchange stack you _can_ edit your questions and answers.

Comment: I think you meant "shortcut" which is not the same as "short cut".

Comment: Your question has been altered a lot.  Could you review the current state of this question and emphasize your main issue?  *I* interpreted the question as "how to reuse keyboard shortcuts on a touch screen device", but it seems like other readers have interpreted your question as "how to implement shortcuts" (ref @Myrddin´s revision).  If the latter is the case, then my answer is irrelevant and I will deleted it.

Comment: @Jack.ak.Hsu See the latest version of my answer, I think it covers most of the possible hotkeys conventions for Windows-style keyboards, when to use them and how to choose them.

Comment: @Danny, I´m not sure if Jack is looking for the actual shortcuts.  That *is* very googable, after all...  (Eg http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/100-keyboard-shortcuts-windows/ and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449)

Comment: I didn't assume he is, I tried to provide guidelines for displaying hotkeys and assigning non-standard hotkeys.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contributions, I am not looking for particular any combinations for actual short cuts, since the tasks are very product specific, in fact, 'help' is the only common task. So any referencing guide would be great on how to assign combination keys.

Comment: After reading through all the comments and answers.
I am torn between following convention of Alt to access menu, Ctrl + key(s) to short cut or to park that instead be product specific, designate Alt/Ctrl/Shift to toggle individual categories follow by short cut keys

Comment: I've just updated the question to "stand alone product" and replaced "on the go" with "multi-tasking"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underlining is the indicator specifically for Alt+Key combinations (An underlined G means pressing Alt+G will be equivalent to clicking on that item). Other types of combinations (Ctrl, Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt, Shift+Alt) must be specified explicitly.

In general, accelerators using the Alt key are for navigation and mouse/touch equivalents (replacing a click or tap). Accelerators using Ctrl are for other functions that need easy access. Ctrl+Shift is for far less common functions. Ctrl+Alt should generally not be used; it is usually reserved for switching to other applications (in Windows), but on other platforms this may be ignored. Shift+Alt is very slow and uncommon to hit, and should be avoided if possible.

Start with the most common commands users execute (do profiling to check) and give those commands the easiest keys to hit and remember. Assign the progressively less common commands the progressively less easy to remember or type keystrokes.

No matter how poorly the mnemonic for remembering the command is, users will eventually master it, so don't stress over the choices too much.

Comment: @ Myrddin Emrys Thanks for the great Answer! This definetly helps with developing the keyboard navigation for the product.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, make use of popular, common shortcuts ( ctrl-c, crtl-v, and so on). For keyboard shortcuts specific to your touchscreen app, it might be a good idea to have tool tips describing the shortcut key show up over the touch screen button when you hold down the ctrl key (or alt, or whatever the shortcut involves).

For example, if there is a "save" button on the touch screen and you held down ctrl, a tooltip would come up over the "save" button that reads "ctrl+s".

While this doesn't totally solve your issue, it might help to add.

Comment: That's a nice idea @DorkRawk ! will definetly look into that as a option. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should, of course, design the product to work properly with touch handeling.  I.e. handle touch/multi-touch as a dedicated input device and implement the gestures you need to get a natural touch interaction with the software.

*I can assure you that your users will try to swipe your lists and pinch your maps/images!*

Likewise I can assure you that the users will be pretty annoyed by tapping the scrollbar arrow buttons, tapping the magnifier glass buttons and fiddling with keyboard shortcuts.

Sometimes, however, this is inevitable...
TeamViewer is one of the Remote Access Solutions that must handle keyboard shortcuts.

1) Create dedicated buttons for some popular combinations (Eg. CTRL+ALT+DEL, CTRL+C, CTRL+V etc)

2) Let the SHIFT, CTRL and ALT buttons be toggable.  Ie when the user hits ALT, then the next button you hit will be ALT + "the ext button".  (Windows has an option for "Sticky keys" in the Accessibility section in the control panel, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-keyboard-easier-to-use).

Comment: The `Alt` key is usually toggable, since `Alt` allow activates the menu, however, using the others (and `Alt` outside menu context) as toggable may confuse users or cause them to invoke the wrong operation. E.g. User clicks `Ctrl` then changes his/her mind prior to clicking on `S` and returns to typing (without clicking on `Ctrl`). **If you do** use sticky keys for the modifier keys, show the status of these keys **when activated** above all windows (like the screen's volume display), so the user will be aware of what will happen.

Comment: @Danny: Yes. Some kind of mode indicator would probably be smart.  This is a general problem, however. The lock keys (caps-lock and scroll-lock) and the dead keys (accent, breve, diaeresis keys etc) have caused a lot of confusion for many people (eg. http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/22468/95). Note that this answer is not a general suggestion, it´s a simple suggestion to the situation where you already *have* a desktop software and want to make usable with a touch screen...  Since the sticky keys feature is already implemented for such situation, it´s probably the easiest way to accomplish that.

Comment: @Danny.  Ehh. Looks like the question has been altered *a lot* since I wrote this answer.  <g>  Now I understand that it might look a bit misleading...  The original issue was how to create a single product that would suit both desktop users with keyboards and "mobile" users with touch screens...

Comment: Thank You @Danny Varod and Jørn E. Angeltveit ! 
On most desktop softwares on both win and OSX I see that the general rule seems to be ATL/Command to access the menu option (e.g. Alt to highlight/toggle follow by either arrow keys or key combinations)
do we think that's a convention for keyboard access? and that the users will gravitate towards that convention when they see a monitor keyboard combination?
we've manage to group the functions into 3 categories now (e.g. file, edit, help) and I am thinking assigning shift/alt/ctrl as individual category toggles could be a reasonable solution.

Comment: @Jack.ak.Hsu I don't think that assigning those keys as category toggles would be a good idea - it would go against what the Ctrl and Shift keys usually do. Instead use Alt+F for file, Alt+E for edit and both Alt+F and F1 for help. Use Ctrl+Key for direct access to options in those menus (without opening menu).

Answer (score 1):

In menus, displaying the hotkey combination that can be used to invoke operation directly (e.g. Save (Ctrl+S) in the File menu) enables users to learn the hotkeys for actions they invoke via menu.

Underlining the accelerators either permanently or when Alt is pressed (and until user has exited menu) can help the users find them.
(E.g. `Alt+F` for the file menu, then `t` for new tab.)
Note that **this kind** of accelerator is localization dependent (depends on language of menus).

Use `Ctrl+letter` for the common operations (`Ctrl+C`/`V`/`X`/`Z`/`Y`/`S`/`F` for copy/pase/cut/undo/redo/save/find).

Use the `Shift` key as a modifier for `Ctrl+Letter` hotkeys (`Ctrl+Shift+Letter`) in order to invoke inverse or advanced operations (e.g. I have seen `Ctrl+Shift+Z` for redo before `Ctrl+Y` caught on, e.g. `Ctrl+Shift+F` for advanced find).

Try to choose the letter that the operation starts with (e.g. `Ctrl+S` for save),
or a letter that resembles the operation (e.g. `Ctrl+Z` for sleep if it wasn't already assigned to undo),
or a letter adjoining similar operations' letter for the operations (e.g. `Ctrl+V` for paste, because it follows `Ctrl+C` (copy) on Qwerty keyboards).

Use the `F-buttons` for operations that do not cause direct side effect on the user's work and may need to be called multiple times in a row - they only require one click. E.g. `F1` for help, `F5` for refresh or for run, `F10` for run one step, `F3` for find/find next.

Use the `Shift` key as a modifier for `F-buttons` too, e.g. `Shift+F3` for advanced find.

Use `Ctrl+Alt+Letter` (or `Ctrl+Alt+FKey` or `Ctrl+Alt+Arrow`) for global hotkeys.
Global hotkeys are hotkeys that work even when your application isn't active (e.g. to launch application or to bring it to focus). Make sure you let the user decide which global hotkeys to use for what (since them may collide with other applications' global hotkeys (first to register on Windows' startup wins).

Use `Ctrl+Left/Right` for backward/forward.

Use `ESC` to cancel operations (e.g. stop in browser, cancel drag and drop, ...).

If you had a mouse, you could use `Ctrl` and `Shift` as modifiers for mouse operations.

Comment: this is a excellent reference list to put towards any future work on keyboard short cuts. thanks @Danny Varod unfortunately we won't have a mouse, which interestingly enough stream lines the interaction model a bit better, since touch and keyboards are polar opposite while touch and mouse conflicts and overlaps.